# Efeitos em links através do hover

Tags: html, css, css3, menu, css-hover

Galera, alguém sabe me dizer como faço esse efeito com `hover`?
Ao passar o mouse sobre o link do menu ele aparecer aquela linha vertical sobre o nome, só consegui com a linha horizontal abaixo do nome.

Ou então me dizer onde encontro exemplos, não encontrei nada sobre isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar um `span` invisível dentro de cada link que só vai aparecer quando o mouse passar sobre o link.

**CSS:**

```
body{ background: #000;}
a{ color: #fff;}
li{ padding: 0px; margin: 0px; list-style: none; display: inline-block; float: left; margin: 10px; position: relative;}
ul{ padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
li span{
    display: none; width: 1px; background: #fff; position:absolute; bottom: 100%; height: 1000px; left: 50%; margin-left: -1px;
}

li:hover span{ display: inline-block;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">Link1</a>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Link2</a>
        <span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/vqfr54w4/](https://jsfiddle.net/vqfr54w4/2/)

Comment: Fecho, obrigado David, exatamente isso

Comment: @Henrique De nada amigo.

Comment: David e caso eu queira deixar a barra aparecendo tipo um active, deixar ela ativa para página que está sendo exibida, como eu faria?